# Сортировка методом подсчёта

Tags: c, сортировка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Недавно начал проходить курс языка Си. На данном этапе возникла такая проблема, что после компиляции выбивает ошибку и main.exe прекращает свою работу. Что не так?
При том, что если делать всю сортировку в main, то всё работает как надо.
Код прилагается

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>


void array_action (int arr[], int N)
{
    int i,j,q,m;
    int a[N];       
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 15 + rand() % 36;
        arr[i] = a[i];
    }
    printf ("Исходный массив: \n");
    for (i=0; i<7; i++) printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}


void sort (int arr[], int N)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int count[51];
    for (i=50; i>=15; i--) 
        for (j=0; j<count[i]; j++)
        {
            arr[k] = i;
            k++;
        }
    printf ("\nЭтап сортировки:\n");
    for (j=0; j<7; j++) printf ("%d ", arr[j]);
    putchar('\n');
    printf ("\nОтсортированный массив:\n");
    for (i=0; i<7; i++) printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}


int main () 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    const int N;
    printf("Введите количество элементов массива: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int arr[N];
    array_action(arr,N);
    sort(arr,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какую ошибку выдаёт? Можно привесту сюда сообщение о ошибке?

Comment: прям сразу "после компиляции выбивает ошибку"? Или Вы все-таки запускаете программу?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь ввести значение для `const int N`

Comment: Получается, что он выводит изначальный массив, а потом сразу выскакивает ошибка

Comment: Ага, то есть не сразу, а какие-то буковки в консоли появляются.

Answer (score 2):

```
void sort (int arr[], int N)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int count[51];
    for (i=50; i>=15; i--) 
        for (j=0; j<count[i]; j++)
        {
            arr[k] = i;
            k++;
        }
```

Как минимум вы используете здесь неинициализированный массив `count` - уже достаточно для UB и непонятно когда останавливающегося цикла...

А уж неинициализированного `k` с головой достаточно для вылета за пределы любого массива :)

И вообще - меня терзает смутное сомнение (с), что ваш код вообще что-то сортирует...

P.S. Просто интересно - чем вы руководствовались здесь:

```
int a[N];       
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    a[i] = 15 + rand() % 36;
    arr[i] = a[i];
}
```

Создавая массив `a`, который нигде не используете? Почему не просто

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    arr[i] = 15 + rand() % 36;
}
```

И еще - почему именно 7 элементов массива? А в остальных что? Если ввести N равным, скажем, 10? Просто мусор? Тогда ваше условие `count[51]` становится смешным...

Comment: У меня сейчас вся жизнь перевернулась. Почему в Си можно ввести значение для `const` переменной? Это UB?

Comment: @EOF С как-то к этому проще относится, чем С++ :) Насколько - тут пусть гуру стандартов говорят. Увы, я просто не заметил этот момент - что N - const... но вообще говоря, в режиме C VC++ такой код пропускает с варнингом, но потом разрешает переписать `N`, а в режиме C++ просто игнорирует введенное.

Comment: [Здесь](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2086.htm) написано: _"Trust the programmer."_. Сразу вспонилась поговорка: _"Доверяй, но проверяй"_ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)

... 

for (i=50; i>=15; i--) 
    for (j=0; j<count[i]; j++)
    {
        arr[k] = i;
```

А `N` Вы зачем туда передаете? И чему в этом месте равно `k`?